# Looking for a comment bubble plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So on my site right now, I just have a little image that a user can click and then they are brought to all the comments for that post. I want to make this dynamic so the bubble contains the # of comments linked to that post inside of it, so the user doesn't have to click the image just to see that there are no comments associated with the post.

Yeah I know I can show/hide the bubble if it has comments or not, but I also want to show the amount, just for simplicity sake.

Worst case scenario is I just show text that says "24 comments", and the text changes to "View Comments" when you hover over it, and is clickable, but I want something a little bit more polished than that.

Is there some sort of a plugin that exists that could do something like this, or does anyone else have any ideas for how I could/should implement it?

Comment: http://www.grupaaquarius.com/kom/ something like? write a comment and look at the bubble with the comment numbers

Comment: Seems like it requires the use of a PHP script and a CMS system? I was looking for something where I could just pass it a #, and it would generate me a comment bubble image.

Comment: It's easy achievable with jQuery and actually on that page it's jQuery that counts the # of comments! (That's for a comment system of yours, right?) I mean: drop here a link to your page so we can see how to help!

Comment: www.jabsy.com - also in my profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the following:

- [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/yXfFC/1/)
- [DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Dy7yL/4/) (balloon counts # of comments)

Comment: Doesn't look to be one of those bubbles in the demo though...=/

Comment: Sorry I started to write and play with codes without seeing your page :\

Comment: lol it's okay. Basically I just want something very simple. Pass it a number, it gives me an image of a comment bubble with that # inside of it.

Comment: Huh... Actually I'm looking at Jabsy and I cannot realize where exactly do you wand that bubble to appear and how you plan to fetch info.

Comment: where the comment bubble is now. right now, every single message has a comment bubble. what we want is every message to have a comment bubble, and ALSO show how many comments there are inside of it :)

Comment: Ahaaaam! now I got it! wait a sec I'll give it a second look

Comment: @slandau let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1594/discussion-between-roxon-and-slandau)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Dy7yL/1/ putting this here so i don't forget it!

Comment: reedited: http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/Dy7yL/4/ now it shows a '0' and a different title if there's no comments